# Deleted ubuntu from dual boot now cant load windows!

Tags: windows

Ive just deleted ubuntu via windows disk management tool and now i cant load windows. I have booted Linux mint from a live usb and can see the windows partition is still there but i dont know how to load it at startup.

Any help would be appreciated

thanks, jay